# Show $\text P\left[|X^x_t|<r\right]\xrightarrow{|x|\to\infty}0$ for strong solutions of SDEs

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $b,\sigma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be Lipschitz continuous
- $(X_t^x)_{t\ge0}$ be a continuous process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$X^x_t=x+\int_0^tb(X^x_s)\:{\rm d}s+\int_0^t\sigma(X^x_s)\:{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\text{ almost surely}\tag1$$ for $x\in\mathbb R$

> Fix $t\ge0$ and $r>0$. I want to show that $$\operatorname P\left[\left|X^x_t\right|<r\right]\xrightarrow{\left|x\right|\to\infty}0.\tag2$$

By Markov's inequality, $$\operatorname P\left[\left|X^x_t\right|<r\right]\le\operatorname P\left[\left|X^x_t-x\right|>\left|x\right|-r\right]\le\frac{\operatorname E\left[\left|X^x_t-x\right|^2\right]}{\left(\left|x\right|-r\right)^2}\tag3$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ with $\left|x\right|-r>0$.

> If $b$ and $\sigma$ are bounded and $\lambda:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left|b(x)\right|^2+\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left|\sigma(x)\right|^2$, then $$\operatorname E\left[\left|X^x_t-x\right|^2\right]\le2\lambda t(t+4)\tag4$$ by Hölder's inequality and the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality. Since the denominator on the right-hand side of $(3)$ tends to $\infty$, we're able to conclude $(2)$.
>
> **Question**: Are we able to prove $(2)$ without assuming boundedness of $b$ and $\sigma$?

By Lipschitz continuity, $$|b(x)|^2+|\sigma(x)|^2\le c(1+|x|^2)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in\mathbb R\tag5$$ for some $c\ge0$. For simplicity of notation, write $|Y|_t^\ast:=\sup_{s\in[0,\:t]}|Y_s|$ for $t\ge0$ and any process $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$. Letting $c_1:=\max(2,4c(t+4)t,4c(t+4))$, we obtain $$\operatorname E\left[{\left|X^x\right|_t^\ast}^2\right]\le c_1\left(x^2+1+\int_0^t\operatorname E\left[{\left|X^x\right|_s^\ast}^2\right]{\rm d}s\right)\tag6$$ by the same argumentation as needed for $(4)$ and hence $$\operatorname E\left[{\left|X^x\right|_t^\ast}^2\right]\le c_1\left(x^2+1\right)e^{c_1t}\tag7$$  by Grönwall's inequality.

> However, I'm not able to utilize $(7)$ to prove $(2)$.$^1$

---

$^1$ compare with [my related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3092872/47771).

Comment: The assertion hold's true if $b$, $\sigma$ are at most of linear growth; otherwise it does, in general, fail to hold true. A more general framework (SDEs driven by Lévy processes) is discussed in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02286).

Comment: @saz In the setting described in the question, they *are* of linear growth (since they are globally Lipschitz, see $(5)$), but I don't see how the assertion can be proved.

Comment: The proof which I know uses Lyapunov functions... I can write it up later.

Comment: @saz That would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straight-forward to check that the function

$$f(x) := \frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

satisfies

$$|f'(x)| \leq 2 |x| f(x)^2 \quad \text{and} \quad |f''(x)| \leq 6 f(x)^2. \tag{1}$$

Applying Dynkin's formula (or Itô's formula) we find that

$$\mathbb{E}f(X_t^x)-f(x) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^t Af(X_s^x) \, ds \right) \tag{2}$$

where

$$Af(x) := b(x) f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(x) f''(x).$$

Because of $(1)$ and the at most linear growth of $b$ and $\sigma$ it follows that we can find a constant $c_1>0$ such that

$$|Af(x)| \leq c_1 f(x) \quad \text{for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$}.$$

Hence, by $(2)$,

$$\mathbb{E}f(X_t^x) \leq f(x) + c_1 \int_0^t \mathbb{E}f(X_s^x) \, ds.$$

Applying Gronwall's lemma we get

$$\mathbb{E}f(X_t^x) \leq f(x) e^{c_2 t}, \qquad t \geq 0, x \in \mathbb{R} \tag{3}$$

for a suitable constant $c_2>0$. Noting that, by the monotonicity of $f$,

$$\{|X_t^x| \leq r\} = \{f(X_t^x) \geq f(r)\}$$

it follows from Markov's inequality and $(3)$ that

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(|X_t^x| \leq r) = \mathbb{P}(f(X_t^x) \geq f(r)) &\leq \frac{1}{f(r)} \mathbb{E}f(X_t^x) \\ &\leq \frac{f(x)}{f(r)} e^{c_2 t}  \end{align*}$$

and the right-hand side converges to $0$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Comment: How do you obtain $|Af(x)| \leq c_1 f(x)$? By linear growth, there is a $c_3$ with $|b(x)|\le c_3(1+|x|)$ and $\sigma^2\le c_3(1+|x|^2)$. This yields $|(Af)(x)|\le 2c_1(1+|x|)|x|f^2(x)+3c_1(1+|x|^2)f^2(x)=2c_1(1+|x|)|x|f^2(x)+3c_1f(x)$. But I don't see how we can eliminate the $f^2$ in the first term.

Comment: @0xbadf00d $f(x)^2 = \frac{1}{x^2+1} f(x)$, and so $$(1+|x|) |x| f(x)^2 \leq (1+|x|)^2 f(x)^2 \leq c_2 f(x)$$ where $$c_2 := \sup_x \frac{(1+|x|)^2}{1+x^2}.$$

Comment: Intuitively it's clear to me that $|\text E[f(X^x_t)]\xrightarrow{|x|\to\infty}0$, if $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$, but how do we need to argue rigorously? Given $ε>0$, we know that there is a $r>0$ with $$|f(x)|<ε\;\;\;\text{for all }|x|\ge r.$$ So, \begin{equation}\begin{split}|\text E[f(X^x_t)]&\le\text E[1_{\left\{\:|X^x_t|\:<\:r\:\right\}}|f(X^x_t)|]+\text E[1_{\left\{\:|X^x_t|\:\ge\:r\:\right\}}|f(X^x_t)|]\\&\le\sup_{|y|<r}|f(y)|\text P[|X^x_t|<r]+ε\text P[|X^x_t|\ge r]\end{split}\end{equation} Clearly, the first tends to $0$ as $|x|→\infty$ and $\text P[|X^x_t|\ge r]\le1$? Is that sufficient?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Well, yes... why should it not be sufficient?

Comment: I've seen that you've deleted your answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140066/47771). Could you tell me what you think about the following idea: The only "good" choice for $\alpha$ is $\alpha=1/2$. With this choice and under appropriate conditions, $\sum_{i=1}^dg'(X_i)(\sigma Z_i)$ converges in distribution (by the central limit theorem) and $\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{g''(X_i)}2(\sigma Z_i)^2$ converges almost surely. Do you think it's possible to show that the second sum tends almost surely to $-\infty$? (But I don't know what to do with the first sum.)